# The smart card has been reset, so any shared state information is invalid

Tags: c#, .net-core, smartcard, apdu, pcsc

I am using PCSC Nuget library for accessing a smart card applets.
I created a load test with JMeter, where there are 20 threads hitting web api endpoint which calls a smart card for some data.
After a while and successful responses, I get this error:
PCSC.Exceptions.PCSCException: 'The smart card has been reset, so any shared state information is invalid.'
Exception is thrown on reader.Transmit call when I send APDU to select appropriate smart card applet.
I all my interface method implementations I am using a lock object and the SmartCard class object is created as a singleton.

```
public class SmartCard
{
    private readonly object lockObj = new object();
    public bool SmartCardMethod1(string data)
    {
        lock (lockObj)
        {
            using (var reader = GetReader())
            {
                var responseSCard = reader.Transmit(CreateAPDUCommand1(reader, data));
            }
        }
    }
    public bool SmartCardMethod2(string data)
    {
        lock (lockObj)
        {
            using (var reader = GetReader())
            {
                var responseSCard = reader.Transmit(CreateAPDUCommand2(reader, data));
            }
        }
    }
    private IsoReader GetReader()
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_readerName))
        {
            SCardContext hContext = new SCardContext();
            hContext.Establish(SCardScope.System);
            var reader = new IsoReader(hContext);

                reader.Connect(_readerName,
                                SCardShareMode.Shared,
                                SCardProtocol.T0 | SCardProtocol.T1);
            var response = reader.Transmit(CreateSelectAppletAPDUCommand(reader));
            if (response.SW1 == 0x90)
            {
                return reader;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting this error on this line:

```
var response = reader.Transmit(CreateSelectAppletAPDUCommand(reader));
```

Comment: Why are you reconnecting to the reader all the time? Why not check the state and only reconnect when required? Besides, you are in shared mode so other processes such as Windows Certificate Propagation Service may interfere...

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Reader and context are disposable, should I create them every time because of that? I need Windows to have access to my smartcard because there is a certificate on a card among applets. There are code examples on PCSC project page, they are using reader in "using" blocks as well.